# Shell to get all the input arguments failed when it contains set -eaux pipefail

Tags: shell

I have a shell script file named `run.sh`, its content is:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eaux pipefail

echo arguments:"$@"
```

When I run: `./run.sh hello`, it print "arguments:pipefail".
But what I want is "arguments:hello".
Why the output is not correct if the script has a `set -eaux pipefail`

Comment: `pipefail` should be used as `-o pipefail`. Please edit `set -eaux pipefail` to `set -eauxo pipefail` and it should work

Comment: Reference: http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/